# Constructor to delegate its argument

Tags: java

Hi I'm having trouble refactoring my code in a better way, and want to ask here on SO for some help.

So, I have a constructor which takes in 4 different interfaces.

```
public Manager(FooSqlInterface foo, BarSqlInterface bar, MooSqlInterface moo, ZaaSqlInterface zaa)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.moo = moo;
        this.zaa = zaa;
    }
```

But, when I use my Manager I always have to send in 4 different interfaces but i'm only using one interface each time.

I would still want to use my manager, but to just delegate the argument that the constructor takes in and pass it to the actual class who use it.

Is there a better way to only take in 1 interface in the constructor, and depending on which interface it is, it will return a instance of that class.

Something like this

```
public Manager(T type)
{
    this.type = type;
    execute();
}

public T execute()
{
    if(type instanceof FooSqlInterface)
    {
        return Foo();
    }
}
```

I have tried to code something like this, but I cannot get it to work. It will only give unchecked type errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you look at the Factory design pattern for this. Thus, you can request the correct implementation by asking the factory to provide it, based on the type that you pass it.

Comment: How about [Method or Constructor Overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) ?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a superinterface for your interfaces?

Comment: you can create factory method also

Comment: If you only use one at a time, why don't you have 4 constructors with a single argument?

Comment: I could use 4 constructors, by my code in the class is really long and hard to search in.

I will check in factory design patter, thanks all! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a super interface if possible? I have tried to make a simple example.

**Main**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    A a = new AImpl();
    B b = new BImpl();
    C c = new CImpl();

    Manager m1 = new Manager(a);
    Manager m2 = new Manager(b);
    Manager m3 = new Manager(c);

    m1.doSomething();
    m2.doSomething();
    m3.doSomething();

}
```

**Super Interface**

```
public interface Alphabetic {

    void execute();
}
```

**Interfaces**

```
public interface A extends Alphabetic {

    void execute();
}
```

.

```
public interface B extends Alphabetic {

    void execute();
}
```

.

```
public interface C extends Alphabetic {

    void execute();
}
```

**Implementations**

```
 public class AImpl implements A {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tester.A#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("I am A");
    }

}
```

.

```
public class BImpl implements B {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tester.A#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("I am B");
    }

}
```

.

```
public class CImpl implements C {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tester.A#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("I am C");
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
I am A

I am B

I am C
```

Comment: @mememax did this help at all?

Comment: well, this looks what I would want. thanks.

But.. My interfaces have different returntypes. FooSqlInterface return lots of Foo, BarSqlInterface return lots of Bar.

Comment: Ah, you could always return Object & cast where you need to, I'm not sure if thats the best idea.

Comment: I will try to experiment with this code, and see if I come up with a solution.
For now i just have 4 different constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I perform the experiment with coding.
using super interface as well as factory pattern.

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package experiment;

/**
 *
 * @author WMads2429175
 */

```
public class Experiment {

    public Experiment() {


        X returnObject;
        Manager m = new Manager(new FooY());
        returnObject=m.execute();
        returnObject.check();

        m = new Manager(new FooZ());
        returnObject=m.execute();
        returnObject.check();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Experiment();
    }

    class Manager {

        X type;

        public Manager(X type) {

            this.type = type;

        }

        public X execute() {

            if (type instanceof  Y) {

                System.out.println("mark 1");

                return new FooY();
            } else if (type instanceof Z) {

                 System.out.println("mark 2");
                return new FooZ();
            }

            return new FooY();

        }
    }

    interface X {

        public void check();
    }

    interface Y extends X {

    }

    interface Z extends X {

    }

    class FooY implements Y {

        public void check() {
            System.out.println("I am Y");
        }
    }

    class FooZ implements Z {

        public void check() {
            System.out.println("I am Z");
        }
    }

}
```